# Android: How to access all files in a folder in internal storage?

Tags: android

I want to access all the files in the music folder in internal storage. I understand that there are ways to access specific files, but is there any way to access all the files in an internal storage folder (without having the name of any of those files)?

Comment: "Internal" storage refers to app-private folders.  More likely you mean the "External Storage" - even if on your device that's located in chips soldered to the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `File` object may represent either a file or a directory.

The [`File`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) object has two methods of potential interest to you:

> public File[] listFiles ()
>
> Added in API level 1
>   Returns an array of files contained in the directory represented by this file. The result is null if this file is not a directory. The paths of the files in the array are absolute if the path of this file is absolute, they are relative otherwise.
>
> Returns
>   an array of files or null.

This should return `null` rather than throw an exception if the `File` is not a directory, but if you want to be sure you can first determine if it actually is a directory:

> public boolean isDirectory ()
>
> Added in API level 1
>   Indicates if this file represents a directory on the underlying file system.
>
> Returns
>   true if this file is a directory, false otherwise.

So, figure out what folder you are interested in, get a `File` object representing it, and then call these methods.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm still getting used to storage on android devices.